# Angular 6 input file, how to display preview of pdf file

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf

I have simple app where I have input where I can upload pdf file and

```
<input (change)="upload($event)"
       multiple
       type="file"/>

<object [data]="file" type="application/pdf">
    <embed [src]="file" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

in upload function:

```
upload(event) {
this.file = event.target.files[0];
}
```

How can I display preview of that file?

Answer (score 0):

**component.html**

```
<input (change)="upload($event)" multiple type="file" />

<object [data]="file" type="application/pdf">
        <embed [src]="file" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
  pdfSrc: string = '/pdf-test.pdf';
  upload(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
     .....

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule]
})
```

You can use the [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) for the same. Install this using `npm i --save ng2-pdf-viewer`

Comment: Is it possible without using PdfViewer? Just using object html tag?

Comment: also add height in  style="display: block; height:200px"